# Creating two arr with same intersect

Tags: javascript, arrays

Right now I need to merge the string into one.

This is my try ->

After this merge i got example of array ->

```
[ 
 [{id: 1, name: "One"}],
 [{id: 2, name : "two"}]
]
```

problem is newData because always print new array.

I need to data be like ->

```
[ 
 {id: 1, name: "One"},
 {id: 2, name : "two"}
]
```

What i am try, with foreEach ->

```
newState((oldData) => [...oldData, newData.forEach((new) => new)]);
```

No work.

Also what I am try

```
 let filteredArray = newData.map(data => data);
```

Also no work, why?

Every time I get new information inside array newData....

I need solution to get only result inside array and print to

```
newState((oldData) => [...oldData, newResultWhichIsObject]);
```

Also some time my newData have few object inside array

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect anything different, but just spread the mapped/filtered array `newState((oldData) => [...oldData, ...newData.map((new) => new)]);` (though `newData.map((new) => new))` doesn't do anthing more than shallow copy the array) Also `foreEach` was never going to work as it **always** [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value) `undefined`.

Comment: You're right. It always returns undefined to me if I use forEach. I need to merge these arrays of mine that I get and always be one array of other objects

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve. Please provide your input array and the desired output array and then mention what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The map method isn't the right method to use in your case. Map method will take as an entry an array of n elements and mutate it into an array of n element, on which an operation was applied. See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

You should use the reduce method, which provides the ability to construct a brand new array from an empty one, here is the snippet :

```js
const baseArray = [ 
 [{id: 1, name: "One"}],
 [{id: 2, name : "two"}]
];

const flattenedArray = baseArray.reduce((acc, curr) => ([...acc, ...curr]), []);

// For demo purpose, console.log
console.log(flattenedArray);
```

Reduce array method is a bit tricky, that is why I invite you to read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) carefully and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method. Try this

```js
const newData = [ 
   [{id: 1, name: "One"}],
   [{id: 2, name : "two"}]
];
console.log(newData.flat())
```